I want to calculate user loss from first open to main screen using custom field
your text
CASE 
 WHEN event name = 'first_open' THEN 1
 WHEN event name = 'SplashOpen' THEN 
  SUM(CASE WHEN "SplashOpen" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 WHEN event name = 'LanguageScreen_Open' THEN 
  SUM(CASE WHEN "LanguageScreen_Open" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 ELSE 0
END


I have putt this formula in looker field and now I'm having following issue
Sorry, calculated fields can't mix metrics (aggregated values) and dimensions (non-aggregated values). Please check the aggregation types of the fields used in this formula

Yea the issue is in error message. You need to remove that SUM() and replace with just a dimension. Or create a derived table that does the SUM already so you can reference it as a dimension.
